# For each row, return the column name of the largest value whilst removing ties

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
x = c(1,1,3, 3, 2)
y = c(1,2,1, 1, 2)
z = c(1,1,2, 3, 7)

data <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

And I would like to get a vector indicating the column number of the highest value in each row; whilst removing ties; or indicate ties with NA.

I have tried which.max:

```
HighestIncludingTies <- apply(data, 1, which.max)
```

Although this does not mark ties with NA (or something similar).

Thanks a lot for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `max.col`:

```
HighsNoTies <- max.col(data,"first")
replace(HighsNoTies, HighsNoTies != max.col(data,"last"), NA)
#[1] NA  2  1 NA  3
```